# Way to check what UIBarButtonItem text is?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm working on an app that has a nav bar and, the "back" button changes to "upgrade" on certain screens. In the app delegate (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) I added some code to get rid of the "back" text and just keep the < arrow by changing the font size to 0.1. That worked, but it hid the text for "upgrade". All I have to do is throw an if statement around that code to check if the UIBarButtonItem's text is equal to @"Back", but i'm not sure what to use.

```
if ([UIBarButtonItem Title] == @"Back")
{
 // Code
}
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ["`backItem`" of your navigation bar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/backItem) and with that, you can get the ["`backBarButtonItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/backBarButtonItem) (which has a ["`.title`" property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBarItem/title)).

In the case where "`backBarButtonItem`" returns nil, then view the [`.title`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/title) property of your navigation item (the "`backItem`").

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:

```
if([self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title isEqualToString:@"Back"]){
   //Your code...
}
```